# How to permanently format the field "Ref" to avoid unwanted spaces after cross reference in Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, field-codes, cross-reference

We have a Word 2010 document where we want to insert cross references to headings. 
When inserting a cross reference (insert -> Cross Reference -> Heading -> Heading (no context) -> ok), the field shows the specific heading number, but 2 spaces are inserted after the field. 
I can permanently remove the spaces by right-clicking the field -> edit field -> click on "Suppress all non-delimiter chars". As this has to be done individually for every cross reference field, I am looking for a way to apply this setting to the cross references insertion field, which is called "Ref". When I change the "Ref" field in the fields menu, the setting is lost upon the next insertion. Please help me with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It has something to do with your numbering list. See this thread http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-word/cross-referencing-issues-unwanted-extra-spaces/1fedeb0a-9a89-4cdb-8fe1-ec252faaa39d

Answer (score 0):

This type of reference does not work when You have numbering format including some additions as chapter level. example 
      Figure 3.1 Blah zig zaq
The way that works for me is making link reference explicitly by copying [Ctrl+C] the wole number (or part of it) of Figure (3.1 in above case) and then insertion it in to test using [paste special] > hyperlink + unformatted text. This will create OLE_LINK that is also REF type. 
Then the field can be automatically updated by Ctrl+A and F9 
P.S.